# Listing available files and directories in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, directory, filesystems

I would like to list available directories and text files in specific directories recursively in Matlab command window (and ultimately in an m-file). I know commands like `ls` are available, but I would like to know the text files available in a string or vector before I recursively read each text file in the following file system structure:

master (contains A and B, all directories)

A contains A1 and A2 (all directories)

A1 contains A11, A12, A13, A14 (all directories)

A11 contains 1.txt, 2.txt, ...

Would be great to hear some feedback! Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab/2654459#2654459.

Comment: If your folders A11, A12, etc. contain no other directories and only the .txt files you are interested in, my solution that mtrw linked to above should work for you without any modification. This will give you a list of all the files: `fileList = getAllFiles('master');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) recursively.

The output of `dir` is a structure where the first and the second element are current and parent directory, respectively, and the rest are the contents of the folder listed. Step through those. If it's a directory (`dirOutput.isdir == 1`), call `dir` on it. If it's a file, add it to the list.

If you don't want to code this yourself, have a look around the [Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20597-improved-file-hounding)'s one of many solutions.