# Matlab, Advanced loop in folders and applying a function

Tags: matlab, loops, file-io, for-loop, directory

i wrote a code that analyze a video file and then plot data on a graph then
save this graph into 
excel and jpg.

but my problem is that i have more than 200 video to analyze in around 20 folder,

so i need to automate this code to loop inside folders and analyze each *.avi file inside and

.. So any ideas or suggestions

Really appreciate your help

**I need to know how to loop folders and get files inside and the apply a function to these files in that folder**

Please note that my function that i also want to save graph result to img, should i then include full path while saving ? and how can i do it ?

Comment: related question: [How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab). Also there are many functions on FEX for recursively traversing directories that you might find useful.. This one for example: [Recursive directory listing](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550-recursive-directory-listing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dir` and `fullfile` commands are what you need.  Depending on your directory structure, something like this:

```
video_dir = 'videos';

% I'm not sure if there's a way to directly get a list of directories, but
% this will work
video_dir_children = dir(video_dir);
video_subdirs = [];
for ix = 1 : length(video_dir_children),
  % note we're careful to kick out '.' and '..' 
  %   (and any other directory starting with a '.')
  if(video_dir_children(ix).isdir && video_dir_children(ix).name(1) ~= '.')
    video_subdirs = [video_subdirs; video_dir_children(ix)];
  end
end

for ix = 1 : length(video_subdirs),
  this_dir = fullfile(video_dir, video_subdirs(ix).name);
  avi_files_in_this_dir = dir(fullfile(this_dir, '*.avi'));

  for jx = 1 : avi_files_in_this_dir,
    doVideoProcessing(fullfile(this_dir, avi_files_in_this_dir(jx).name));
  end

end
```

Comment: Vectorized test can make that first loop more concise: `video_subdirs = video_dir_children([video_dir_children.isdir] & ~ismember({video_dir_children.name}, {'.','..'}))`.

Comment: thats great :), just one more question,in my video processing i save files for each video result "saveas(h,[b '.jpg']);" , but its not working with loop , any way to solve ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  You may need to construct the path of the file using `fullfile`.