# is it possible to search for a particular expression/entry in a file inside a folder in matlab?

Tags: matlab

is there a command to search for a 'particular entry inside the files present in a folder' in matlab?
like if i want to search for the word "hello" in all the files present in folder A.

```
allFiles = dir( 'G:\folder\myfilename' );
allNames = { allFiles.name };
```

only lets me search for a particular file in a specific folder.:(

Comment: You mean like Linux' `grep -r "*hello*" *`? Both answers seem to be focusing on finding *file names* containing "\*hello\*", but I think you're asking for a "\*hello\*" in the *any file's contents*...is this true?

Comment: Yes.Like if i have search for a particular entry in nested folders(folder A has 20 more folders in it and i need to search for an entry within every folder and sub folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654459/201800) to get you a list of all files in a directory.

Then you can use [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html) to identify any files containing the string `'hello'`.

Or as Peter D points out:

> I found it useful to build in regular expressions into the function.
>
> ```
> if ~isempty(fileList)     
>    fileList = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(dirName,x),'UniformOutput',false);
>    matchstart =  regexp(fileList, pattern); 
>    fileList = fileList(~cellfun(@isempty,  matchstart));
> end
> ```
>
> and change the function signature to
>
> `getAllFiles(dirName, pattern)` (also in the 2nd to last line)

Comment: Actually, looks like the last commentator on that question has laid the groundwork for doing exactly what you want to do. I'll add his quote to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use wildcards:

```
 allFiles = dir( 'G:\folder\myfilename\*hello*.*' );
```

Comment: What if there are sub folders inside the main folder and i need to search for a particular entry for all files in the sub folders as well?

Comment: on running the above command i get

allFiles = 

0x1 struct array with fields:
    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum