# MATLAB: import all files from multiple directories and create a single column vector of 2 of the variables

Tags: file, matlab, import, directory

I am a beginner in MATLAB coding so I have taken code from else-ware to apply it to my own needs. I've so far managed to get all files from one folder into a column vector, but now I want to get all files from all folders within a parent directory into this single column vector.
here's my code:

...

```
folder = ('parent_directory_path_name\01');     
files = eval(['dir(''' folder '\*wind*.na'')']); % take files with wind in name
N = length(files);

%%

for n=1:N

    filename = files(n).name;
    eval(['fid = fopen(''' folder '/' filename ''');']) 
    data=textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n');
    lines=data{1};
    lines=lines(56:end);

        for i=1:size(lines,1)
            [s(i).time s(i).east s(i).north] = strread(lines{i},'%f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f');
        end

    time = [s.time]';
    east (:,n) = [s.east]';
    north(:,n) = [s.north]';

fclose(fid);

end

%%

ea = east (:);      % put matrix columns into 1 column
no = north (:);
```

...

I'm sure there must be a simple loop I can put around the folder specification, but I can't work it out. I've also looked at: 
[How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab) , but as the method is very different I'm unsure how to apply this to the code I'm using.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Luke

***EDIT***

Re:Shai, (comments section not big enough)

Okay, I've given it a try but I don't get how to open the files now. Here's what I've tried:

```
sub_f = dir( fullfile( 'parent_folder', '*' ) );
for si = 1:numel( sub_f )
    if sub_f(si).name(1) =='.', continue; 
    end; % skip '.' and '..'
    files = dir( fullfile( 'parent_folder', sub_f(si).name, '*wind*.na' ) ); % get all files in sub folder
    for n = 1:numel(files)
         % put your code here...
        filename = files(n).name;
        fid = fopen('' sub_f '/' filename '');
        data=textscan(fid, '%s','delimiter','\n');
        lines=data{1};
        lines=lines(56:end);
        for i=1:size(lines,1)
            [s(i).time s(i).east s(i).north] = strread(lines{i},'%f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f');
        end
        time = [s.time]';
        east (:,n) = [s.east]';
        north(:,n) = [s.north]';
        fclose(fid);

    end
end
```

Thanks again!

Comment: you should replace the line `filename=filse(n).name` with the following line: `filename = fullfile('parent_folder',sub_f(si).name,files(n).name)`

Comment: Thanks again.
I still can't get it to work, but i've done it manually for now.
I will come back to it later when I need to do this for more folders.
Cheers

Comment: it would help if you'd be more specific when you say "can't get it to work": what is the error? where does it fails?

Comment: Please don't feel obliged to answer as I should really spend some time learning about this myself. But if you like here's the error:

Error: File: script Line: ...
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

corresponding to `(fid = fopen('' sub_f '/' filename '');)` 
I think it's the '/' that doesn't work as I thought

Comment: @Shai please see above comment

Comment: After changing the `filename` line, you need to change the `fopen` line to : `fid = fopen( filename );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

1. instead of concatenating folder names and file names as simple strings, a better practice would be to use `fullfile` command:

   `folder = fullfile( 'parent_folder', '01' );`
2. You do not need the cumbersome `evel` expressions:

   `files = dir( fullfile( folder,  '*wind*.na' ) );`
3. For iterating over sub folders you can simply do

   ```
   sub_f = dir( fullfile( 'parent_folder', '*' ) );
   for si = 1:numel( sub_f )
       if sub_f(si).name(1) =='.', continue; end; % skip '.' and '..'
       files = dir( fullfile( 'parent_folder', sub_f(si).name, '*wind*.na' ) ); get all files in sub folder
       for n = 1:numel(files)
            % put your code here...
       end
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't get this to work so have done it manually this time as I only have 12 folders.

Comment: @user1909613 - please see my comment to your edited question.