# how to import data from multiple folders in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have my data in multiple folders. Let's say I have a folder containing 100 subfolders at the moment that look like this:

```
/folder/Re0001/vitesse
/folder/Re0002/vitesse
/folder/Re000N/vitesse
/folder/Re000N+1/vitesse
/folder/Re0100/vitesse
```

I want to import the `vitesse` file into a cell array. This is the code that i am using at the moment:

```
numfiles=100;

mydata=cell(1,numfiles);

for i=1:numfiles

    mydata{i}=uiimport;

end
```

It is a working solution.

However, if it involves `100` or more files I have to specify each folders and files manually, which is very troublesome.

By the way I am new to Matlab so can you please incorporate example code with the directory given.

Comment: Check [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar few days ago. Have a look at the [matlab function ls](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html). If you are using windows system, you are all set. If your are using linux, you may need to split the results. However newer version of matlab have the [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) function that will do the job, or you will use regular expressions.
In your case,

```
list = ls('/folder/*/vitesse');
```

will give you a list of your files.

Comment: Soory it does not work it says :

Comment: What is the result of ls command looking like?

Comment: the following post maybe the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab?lq=1