# Loop over folders?

Tags: matlab, loops, directory

I have the code like this:

```
          myFolder='C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat\1';
          filePattern=fullfile(myFolder, '*.txt');
          txtFiles=dir(filePattern);
```

Now, dat is a folder that contains "1,2,3" folders and each one of these folders contains 20 TXT files. 
The previous code is able to get the txt files from 1 folder. Now my question is: is there a way to loop over all the directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is :)

A very nice function is this one:

[by gnovice: getAllFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab)

You can use it like this:

```
fileList = getAllFiles('D:\dic');
```

Then you just have to get rid of non-txt-files, e.g. by checking the extension within a loop!

Comment: But in this case i will not able to control all the data *too much dat.. I have like 20 sub folder?

Comment: well, this is something special... what error-message do you get then?

Comment: nooo. It works really but I just got all txt in thess folders , so i will not able to control this txt files .

Comment: what do you mean by "control"? you could filter the results afterwards, if there are too many files or if there are folders you dont want to include.

Comment: Ok .every folder contains 3 floders , and each folder contain like 20 txt files. These txt files starting form 1 to 20 in all folders.

Comment: this answer works very well but you need more errofrt to filter the files (in case the file names were simmilar)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another possibility, using the apache commons library that comes with MATLAB:

```
function fileNames = findAllFiles(directory, wildcardPattern)

    import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.*;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import java.io.File;

    files = FileUtils.listFiles( File(directory),...
                                 WildcardFileFilter(wildcardPattern),...
                                 FileFilterUtils.trueFileFilter());

    fileNames = cellfun(@(f) char(f.getCanonicalPath()),...
                        cell(files.toArray()),...
                        'uniformOutput', false);
end
```

Use e.g. as:

```
files = findAllFiles('C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat', '*.txt')
```

If you'd like to also apply a pattern on the directory-names in which the search should descend, you can simply replace the `FileFilterUtils.trueFileFilter()` with another `WildcardFileFilter`.

Comment: Is it possible to use this but on folders? Like, is it possible to loop over folder names and not files? Hence, the result would be a list of folders (path) with a specified name?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do something like

```
for k=1:3
    myFolder{k}=['C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat\' num2str(k)];
    filePattern{k}=fullfile(myFolder{k}, '*.txt');
    txtFiles{k}=dir(filePattern{k});
end
```

You can obviously pre-allocate the sizes of the arrays / cell arrays if performance/memory is an issue.

Comment: I did not get how to pre-allocate the sizes of the arrays   ? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: second one                                                                        myFolder(k)=['C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat\' num2str(k)];

Comment: I mean explain more what do you mean by cell array here??

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html. I edited my answer to use {k} instead (k)

Comment: If i want to use the txt file to perfom some tasks. can i use this   `txtFiles{k}=dir(filePattern{k}.name);`

Comment: like this `for k=1:3
    myFolder{k}=['C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat\' num2str(k)];
    filePattern{k}=fullfile(myFolder{k}, '*.txt');
    txtFiles{k}=dir(filePattern{k}.name);
end `

Answer (score 1):

You can use the recursive version of Matlab's function [`fileattrib`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fileattrib.html), and then select the txt files with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html). This solution works for any number of folders and any level of nesting.

```
[success,message,messageid] = fileattrib('C:\Users\abe7rt\Desktop\dat\*');
[names{1:numel(message)}] = deal(message.Name);
names_txt = names(~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(names,'\.txt$')));
```

The cell array `names_txt` contains the full names of all txt files. So `names_txt{n}` is a string with the full name of the n-th file.

Make sure you add the final `\*` to the root path.