# Matlab: filesystem, string manipulation and figures saving

Tags: string, filesystems, matlab

In the workspace I have many m-files containing data I'd like to plot.
I have to read them all and save their plot without showing the results (I'll see them after all is done).
The last part can be done this way?

```
f = figure('Visible', 'off');
plot(x,y);
saveas(f,'figure.fig');
```

but I don't want to load manually each m-file where x and y are stored.
So I need a way to explore the filesystem and run these statements for each file, manipulate their name and save a jpg with the same name of its m-file.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` function will return a structure containing info on the Folders and Files in the current directory

```
>> FileInfo = dir
```

Then you need to write code to use that info to automatically navigate the directory structure (using `cd` for instance), and select the files you want to read.

The function `what` can also be useful if you're wanting to  only look for certain file types, e.g. .mat files.

Not surprisingly, similar questions to this have been asked before, for instance see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab)