# How to use the obtained direction from "dir" to address the "dlmread" & "xlsread"

Tags: matlab

I want to read some "xlsx" & "txt" files from directory and process on that. Names of the files are the random word. 
so I used a `function(getAllFiles)` to obtain all directions of those files which I founded in this link: [How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab).
when I want to use those direction in `dlmread` or `xlsread` it give an error as bellow:

```
 ??? Error using ==> dlmread at 55
 Filename must be a string.
```

the code is as follow :

```
fileList =  getAllFiles('/home/Network/econimi/SSS')
A=dlmread(fileList(2));
```

how can I convert `fileList` to the string format?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `getAllFiles` is a cell array. As stated in [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) 'Cell array indices in smooth parentheses refer to sets of cells' which means `fileList(2)` is a cell as well. To access an element of a cell array, use curvy brackets.

Try:

```
A=dlmread(fileList{2});
```