# how to put unequal dimensional excel files in n*m array?

Tags: matlab

I want to read E columns of every excel files which do not have equal dimensions and put them into a n*m dimensional array.
I used a function named as `getAllFiles` to obtain all files in a directory. I found the function in this link: [How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab).
Here's my code:

```
fileList =  getAllFiles('C:\Users\asus\Network\econimi\S&P500\P1')

for i=1:length(fileList)
    A(i,:)=xlsread(fileList{i},'E:E');
end
```

I see following error as soon as it puts the data of the first file:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension
mismatch.
```

Answer (score 0):

Output of `xlsread` function is a Matrix or a Vector (depending on your xls data). When you use `A(i,:)=xlsread(fileList{i},'E:E');` you are saying to MATLAB that you want to assign a Matrix or a Vector to *i* th row and all ( *:* ) columns of A Matrix. Since A Matrix does not exist in the first iteration of your loop, it would be created depending on your assignment rvalue (`xlsread` output which seems to be n x 1 in the first iteration).
In the second iteration you seem to assign a Matrix to the A(i,:) Vector which is not allowed (does not seem rational to put a Matrix into a Vector).
Now you say that you have matrices with different dimensions in your xls files. If you are insisting on appending all of them into a matrix, you must first decide what you want to do with the empty indexes. Say you want to append a 3x3 matrix to a 2x2! You can turn the 2x2 into 3x2 and the append it to the 3x3 to have a 3x5 matrix. This way you will have two zero values in 3x2 matrix.