# Matlab: Get full path of sub-directories and files

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have a directory at `'../../My_Dir'` relative to the Matlab working directory. This directory itself has several sub-directories in it. Each sub-directory then has several files in it.

I want to create two-dimensional array, or a matrix, of strings. Each row represents one of the sub-directories. The first column in the row is the **full path** to the sub-directory itself, and the other columns are the **full paths** to the files within that sub-directory.

Can anyone show me some code that will help me to implement this? Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab) question.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the sub-folders by

```
d = dir(pathFolder);
isub = [d(:).isdir];
subFolders = {d(isub).name}';
```

Note, you further need to remove `.` and `..` from it:

```
subFolders(ismember(subFolders,{'.','..'})) = [];
```

And then get files in each of them by using (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654459/2589776)):

```
function fileList = getAllFiles(dirName)

    dirData = dir(dirName);      %# Get the data for the current directory
    dirIndex = [dirData.isdir];  %# Find the index for directories
    fileList = {dirData(~dirIndex).name}';  %'# Get a list of the files
    if ~isempty(fileList)
        fileList = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(dirName,x),...  %# Prepend path to files
            fileList,'UniformOutput',false);
    end
    subDirs = {dirData(dirIndex).name};  %# Get a list of the subdirectories
    validIndex = ~ismember(subDirs,{'.','..'});  %# Find index of subdirectories
    %#   that are not '.' or '..'
    for iDir = find(validIndex)                  %# Loop over valid subdirectories
        nextDir = fullfile(dirName,subDirs{iDir});    %# Get the subdirectory path
        fileList = [fileList; getAllFiles(nextDir)];  %# Recursively call getAllFiles
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a help, but I am now getting the following error when I loop through subFolders, and call dir() on each element: `Error using dir. Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs`

Comment: @Karnivaurus Try use something like `dir(dirName{1,1})` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folders FULL PATH:

```
d = dir(baseDir);
d(~[d.isdir])= []; %Remove all non directories.
names = setdiff({d.name},{'.','..'});

filesFullPath = names;

for i=1:size(names,2)
    filesFullPath{i} = fullfile(baseDir,names{1,i});
end

Matlab... "thanks" for this s...
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example, let's say I have three subfolders in `'My_Dir'` called `'A'` (containing `'a1.txt'` and `'a2.txt'`), `'B'` (containing `'b1.txt'`), and `'C'` (containing `'c1.txt'`, `'c2.txt'`, and `'c3.txt'`). This will illustrate how to handle a case with different numbers of files in each subfolder...

For MATLAB versions R2016b and later, the [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function supports recursive searching, allowing us to collect a list of files like so:

```
dirData = dir('My_Dir\*\*.*');        % Get structure of folder contents
dirData = dirData(~[dirData.isdir]);  % Omit folders (keep only files)
fileList = fullfile({dirData.folder}.', {dirData.name}.');  % Get full file paths

fileList =

  6×1 cell array

    '...\My_Dir\A\a1.txt'
    '...\My_Dir\A\a2.txt'
    '...\My_Dir\B\b1.txt'
    '...\My_Dir\C\c1.txt'
    '...\My_Dir\C\c2.txt'
    '...\My_Dir\C\c3.txt'
```

As an alternative, in particular for earlier versions, this can be done using a utility I posted to the MathWorks File Exchange: [`dirPlus`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/60716-dirplus). It can be used as follows:

```
dirData = dirPlus('My_Dir', 'Struct', true, 'Depth', 1);
fileList = fullfile({dirData.folder}.', {dirData.name}.');
```

Now we can format `fileList` in the way you specified above. First we can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get a list of unique subfolders and an index. That index can then be used with [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) and [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to break `fileList` up by subfolder into a second level of cell array encapsulation:

```
[dirList, index] = unique({dirData.folder}.');
outData = [dirList mat2cell(fileList, diff([index; numel(fileList)+1]))]

outData =

  3×2 cell array

    '...\My_Dir\A'    {2×1 cell}
    '...\My_Dir\B'    {1×1 cell}
    '...\My_Dir\C'    {3×1 cell}
```