# Loading several text files from multiple folders

Tags: matlab

I'm busy with a research and I'm gonna use Matlab to research the data.
But I'm having trouble loading all my text files into Matlab without getting in insanely long code!

The setup is like this:

```
Testsubject1/ts1_bla.txt
Testsubject2/ts2_bla.txt
```

I myself use Dutch sentences for this, but i guess the routine is the same where as the `bla` part are several files.

I'm able to use this code for 1 directory, but then i have to switch directory to load the data everytime:

```
files = dir('.\Proefpersoon1\*.txt');
for i=1:length(files)
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
end
```

I also don't mind just keeping them as arrays, but is there a way to make a loop with this?

```
files = dir('.\Proefpersoon1\*.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of: [How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab)

function is as follows:

```
function fileList = getAllFiles(dirName)

  dirData = dir(dirName);      %# Get the data for the current directory
  dirIndex = [dirData.isdir];  %# Find the index for directories
  fileList = {dirData(~dirIndex).name}';  %'# Get a list of the files
  if ~isempty(fileList)
    fileList = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(dirName,x),...  %# Prepend path to files
                   fileList,'UniformOutput',false);
   end
  subDirs = {dirData(dirIndex).name};  %# Get a list of the subdirectories
  validIndex = ~ismember(subDirs,{'.','..'});  %# Find index of subdirectories
                                           %#   that are not '.' or '..'
  for iDir = find(validIndex)                  %# Loop over valid subdirectories
    nextDir = fullfile(dirName,subDirs{iDir});    %# Get the subdirectory path
    fileList = [fileList; getAllFiles(nextDir)];  %# Recursively call getAllFiles
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reaction!

But I'm not sure what to change in your code so that it's usable for me :(

Comment: @User3582302 I added some comments to clarify what each line does. Does this help? In what way is the code not working? Does it throw an error or return an incorrect result?

Comment: I'm getting this error:

>> bla = DataLaden('D:\Desktop\BOP Metingen\')

files = 

     {}

Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in DataLaden (line 8)
  if isdir(tmpnames{i}) %if its a subdirectory

Comment: Rather than fix mine you can just use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab

Comment: Well i tried it, but i will just give me a huge cell.. from which i'm unable to load/use my data (from the text file that are in the cell format)

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? The cell array is too large and you are running out of memory? Don't forget to index the cell array with `{}` and NOT `()`.

Comment: Well the issues now is that i'm not sure how to load my .txt data that now is stored in the cell. They are currently stored as strings with the path directory in the cell.

Comment: matlab has many tools for loading data. Such as [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) and [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for formatted text files and then there are the [C-like tools](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/low-level-file-i-o.html). My recommendation would probably be textscan.