# reading in all text files from specific directory

Tags: matlab, directory, dir

I started learning matlab very recently and am stuck on this issue.

My code looks like this:

```
fileloc = '/no_backup/GroupData/ESRL/Download_18Mar2014/surface/'
list = dir(fileloc, '*.txt') 
numTextFiles = length(list) 
disp(numTextFiles)
```

So far I am just checking to see if it has read in the correct amount of text files, but it gives me the error:

```
"Error using dir
Too many input arguments."
```

I tried replacing

```
list = dir(fileloc, '*.txt')
```

to

```
list = dir(strcat(fileloc, '*.txt'))
```

(just in case my syntax was completely wrong since I have no idea)

but then it prints

```
numTextFiles =
       0
       0
```

I am just wondering if any of the functions I'm using are inappropriate and if so, which ones would I use/how would I use those and how would I just display the number of text files I have in that folder?

Comment: Have a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

the argument to `dir` should be `directoryname/*.txt` or `directoryname\*.txt` if you're on windows.  you can achieve this with

```
list = dir([ fileloc filesep '*.txt' ]);
```

`[]` concatenates strings.  `filesep` is a builtin that evaluates to a string of the separator for your OS.

Comment: i'm actually on unix..this doesn't work :( same output for numTextFiles = 0 0

Comment: it works on my machine.  is the code you have here the exact code you are running?  print `list`.  what does it say?

Comment: When I use your suggestion (list = dir([fileloc filesep '*.txt']); it says:

list = 
0x1 struct array with fields:
   name
   date
   bytes
   isdir
   datenum



numTextFiles = 
   0
   0

Comment: are you sure there are .txt files in that location?  are you sure fileloc is correct?