# Searching for files in a folder using uigetdir in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

How can i search for files of a particular type say `.jpg` files in a particular folder using `uigetfile()`?

It will be very helpful if files in the sub-folders can also be searched for?

Comment: What you mean by "search"?

Comment: For example I select a folder which contains several sub-folders, so I want the paths of say all the .jpg files in each sub-folder and the folder itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first fetch all files from the directory (and subdirectories).
There's an excellent answer for this problem. Look here:
[How to get all files under a specific directory in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab).
To select the folder you can use the matlab command: *uigetdir*

Subsequently just loop over the list and collect all names that end with ".jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the image file');
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) for more details.

Comment: Actually, I want to browse a directory and inside this I want the paths of all the .jpg files.

Comment: Then your question is badly formulated. You don't want to use `uigetfile` at all, but rather `dir`. Again check the documentation, it's fairly obvious what you need to do.