# Trouble opening files from filelist in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filenames, fopen

I have a list of filenames saved in a 51X1 cell matrix
obtained by using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652630/how-to-get-all-files-under-a-specific-directory-in-matlab) and
i want to use fastaread or any other matlab txt reading function
to read those files.

They are in the following form:

```
C:\Users\mixalic\Desktop\fastasequences\AB062619_FASTA_328312477664609773.txt
```

the problem is that when i use

```
fastaread(filelist(i))
```

i get the following error:

```
Error using fastaread (line 53)
Input must be a character array
```

i tried to convert my cell array to character array but then it will only read C:
and report:

```
Error using fastaread (line 158)
Input does not exist or is not a valid FASTA file.
```

or when i use load:

```
Error using load
Unable to read file C: No such file or directory.
```

Any help?

Thank you very much

Comment: `fastaread(filelist{i})` should work. If it doesn't, check `exist(filelist{i},'file')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the elements of the `filelist` with curly brackets. If you use normal brackets Matlab returns a 1x1 cell array.

This

```
filelist = {'C:/path/to/file.txt'};
foo = filelist(1);
bar = filelist{1};
whos 'foo' 'bar'
```

outputs:

```
Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
bar       1x19               38  char               
foo       1x1               150  cell
```

Comment: thanks, i initially solved it by a char conversion but that's better